# Need Help for Dynamic Optimization: Error Message: f0 passed has more than 1 dimension within Optimization Algorithm

Tags: python

I want to optimize a rocket trajectory. The Problem I want to solve is described in this video: #https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9qsiCGpvwKA&t=332s. It's about finding the minimal time for a rocket to get from zero altitude and zero velocity in the beginning to an altitude of 10 and a velocity of zero at final time. There's a solution provided in the mentioned video, but I want to solve the Problem on my own without using the Toolbox of APMonitor.

I set up this code as my objectiveFunction to optimize, by using 8 control Points for Controlling the rocket's trajectory:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate

def rocketmotion(t, Y, x, z):
    f = interpolate.interp1d(x, z) 
    if t>x[1]:
        u=f(x[1])
    else:
        u=f(t)
    s=Y[0];   v=Y[1];   m=Y[2]
    ds_dt=v
    dv_dt=(u-0.2*v**2)/m
    dm_dt=-0.01*u**2
    return [ds_dt, dv_dt, dm_dt]


def objectiveFunction(x, other_args):
    
    n_Gridpoints=8
    u=np.zeros(n_Gridpoints)
    u[0]=x[1]; u[1]=x[2];  u[2]=x[3]; u[3]=x[4]; u[4]=x[5]; u[5]=x[6]; u[6]=x[7]; u[7]=x[8]
    

    Y0=[0, 0, 1]
    t_end=x[0]
    

    time_steps=np.linspace(0, t_end, n_Gridpoints)

    T=[]; S=[]; V=[]; M=[]

    for i in range(n_Gridpoints-1):

        x=[time_steps[i], time_steps[i+1]]
        z=[u[i], u[i+1]]
                
        if i==0:
    
            Y = solve_ivp(rocketmotion,[0, time_steps[i+1]],Y0, args=[x, z])       
        
        else: 
        
            Y = solve_ivp(rocketmotion,[time_steps[i], time_steps[i+1]], [Y.y[0][-1], Y.y[1][-1], Y.y[2][-1]], args=[x, z])       

        T.extend(Y.t)  
        S.extend(Y.y[0])
        V.extend(Y.y[1])
        M.extend(Y.y[2])
    
    execMode=other_args
     
    if execMode==1:
    
        return T[-1]+abs(10-S[-1])*10+abs(V[-1])*10
    
    elif execMode==2:
        
        print((T[-1]+abs(10-S[-1])*10+abs(V[-1])*10).ndim)
        return T[-1]+abs(10-S[-1])*10+abs(V[-1])*10
        
    else:  
        
        print((T[-1]+abs(10-S[-1])*10+abs(V[-1])*10).ndim)
        print(T[-1]+abs(10-S[-1])*10+abs(V[-1])*10)
        return T, S, V, M
```

I am using Reward Shaping to make sure that the final condition (Postion=10, Velocity=0) will be reached. Now I am trying to use SLSQP for Optimizing the given function:

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize

bounds_time=(5, 15)
bounds_u=(-1.1, 1.1)
bounds=[bounds_time, bounds_u, bounds_u, bounds_u, bounds_u, bounds_u, bounds_u, bounds_u, bounds_u]
x0=[7.5, 1.1, 1.1, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, -1.0, -0.8]
execMode=2
other_args=[execMode]

solution = minimize(objectiveFunction,x0,method='SLSQP', bounds=bounds, args=other_args, \
    options={'maxiter': 1000, 'disp': True})
```

I get the error message: `f0` passed has more than 1 dimension. This error message occurs within the Function approx_derivative that is used by the SLSQP Algorithm. I don´t understand this error message. Therefore I would like to ask you for help.
The Traceback is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-76-4be01f8fa5f5> in <module>
      9 other_args=[execMode]
     10 
---> 11 solution = minimize(objectiveFunction,x0,method='SLSQP', bounds=bounds, args=other_args, \
     12     options={'maxiter': 1000, 'disp': True})
     13 

~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_minimize.py in minimize(fun, x0, args, method, jac, hess, hessp, bounds, constraints, tol, callback, options)
    623         return _minimize_cobyla(fun, x0, args, constraints, **options)
    624     elif meth == 'slsqp':
--> 625         return _minimize_slsqp(fun, x0, args, jac, bounds,
    626                                constraints, callback=callback, **options)
    627     elif meth == 'trust-constr':

~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\slsqp.py in _minimize_slsqp(func, x0, args, jac, bounds, constraints, maxiter, ftol, iprint, disp, eps, callback, finite_diff_rel_step, **unknown_options)
    367 
    368     # ScalarFunction provides function and gradient evaluation
--> 369     sf = _prepare_scalar_function(func, x, jac=jac, args=args, epsilon=eps,
    370                                   finite_diff_rel_step=finite_diff_rel_step,
    371                                   bounds=new_bounds)

~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\optimize.py in _prepare_scalar_function(fun, x0, jac, args, bounds, epsilon, finite_diff_rel_step, hess)
    259     # ScalarFunction caches. Reuse of fun(x) during grad
    260     # calculation reduces overall function evaluations.
--> 261     sf = ScalarFunction(fun, x0, args, grad, hess,
    262                         finite_diff_rel_step, bounds, epsilon=epsilon)
    263 

~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_differentiable_functions.py in __init__(self, fun, x0, args, grad, hess, finite_diff_rel_step, finite_diff_bounds, epsilon)
     93 
     94         self._update_grad_impl = update_grad
---> 95         self._update_grad()
     96 
     97         # Hessian Evaluation

~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_differentiable_functions.py in _update_grad(self)
    169     def _update_grad(self):
    170         if not self.g_updated:
--> 171             self._update_grad_impl()
    172             self.g_updated = True
    173 

~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_differentiable_functions.py in update_grad()
     89                 self._update_fun()
     90                 self.ngev += 1
---> 91                 self.g = approx_derivative(fun_wrapped, self.x, f0=self.f,
     92                                            **finite_diff_options)
     93 

~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_numdiff.py in approx_derivative(fun, x0, method, rel_step, abs_step, f0, bounds, sparsity, as_linear_operator, args, kwargs)
    386         f0 = np.atleast_1d(f0)
    387         if f0.ndim > 1:
--> 388             raise ValueError("`f0` passed has more than 1 dimension.")
    389 
    390     if np.any((x0 < lb) | (x0 > ub)):

ValueError: `f0` passed has more than 1 dimension
```

Comment: Please give full traceback.

Comment: the full traceback is:

Comment: added to the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) showing the problem:

```py
from scipy.optimize import minimize

x0=[7.5, 1.1, 1.1, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, -1.0, -0.8]
execMode=2
other_args=[execMode]

def objectiveFunction(x, other_args):
    execMode=other_args
    print(execMode)
    return x

solution = minimize(objectiveFunction, x0, method='SLSQP', args=other_args)
```

And it prints a bunch of `[2]` before crushing. You expected `2` instead (I know it from `elif execMode==2:`). Hence, the simple solution is:

```
def objectiveFunction(x, other_args):
    ...
    execMode=other_args[0]
    ...
```

As you see, after MRE is prepared, it's much easier to solve the problem. That's why you're asked to post it on stackoverflow.